# How to count the number of quarters between two dates

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

### Question 1:

How would you count the number of quarters between the starting date (`base_date` variable) and the `y` column in the pandas dataframe?

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

base_date=pd.to_datetime('07/01/2019')
fake_data=pd.DataFrame([(x,pd.to_datetime('04/01/2020')+relativedelta(months=y)) for x in list(range(0,100)) for y in list(range(0,100))],columns=['x','y'])
fake_data['z']=fake_data['x']*np.random.uniform(low=1,high=1000)
```

UPDATE: one option seems to work for question1:

```
fake_data['month_diff']=(fake_data['y'].dt.year-base_date.year)*12+fake_data['y'].dt.month-base_date.month
fake_data['quarter']=(fake_data['month_diff']/3).astype(int)
```

### Question 2:

If the `x` and `y` variables are now set to a pandas dataframe multi-level index.  How would you perform the same task as in question 1?

```
fake_data.set_index(['x','y'],drop=True,inplace=True)
```

Comment: Question 1: Have you tried [resampling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) your data to quarters in a separate dataset to determine the number of quarters covered?  The different time samples are defined in [this doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects).

Comment: I am evauluating this:  `fake_data.resample('M',level=1,fill_method=None).asfreq()` however it is post a ValueError.  Aside, my assumption if it does work it will not post an increment.  Meaning, after year 1 the quarter function would start over at 1-4 again.  The FILL_METHOD in my version does not seem to be documented.  As the documentation shows, NaN will be posted for non-quarter end dates.  Jan=Feb=NaN, Mar=1 for the quarter.  I would need to ensure that Jan=Feb=Mar=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question 1:

A year contains 4 quarters. A simple way to count the difference of quarters between to dates is to convert them to *year * 4 + quarter* and use the difference:

```
fake_data.y.dt.year * 4 + fake_data.y.dt.quarter - (base_date.year * 4 + base_date.quarter)
```

Question 2:

The previous method still applies, but on `index.levels[1]`:

```
fake_data.index.levels[1].year * 4 + fake_data.index.levels[1].quarter - (base_date.year * 4 + base_date.quarter)
```

Simply in first question you get a plain Series, while here it is an Index...

Answer (score 4):

This is a pretty neat way to use pandas built-in period differencing:

```
import pandas as pd
t = pd.to_datetime('2025Q4').to_period(freq='Q') - pd.to_datetime('1850Q2').to_period(freq='Q')
print(t.n)  # -> 702
```

For dates in a series, you will need to use a lambda:

```
import pandas as pd
# Setup
data = {'end': ['2023-01-01', '2023-04-01', '2023-07-01'],
        'start': ['2022-12-01', '2023-01-01', '2023-01-01']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end'])
df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start'])

#Compute the difference in quarters
diff = (df['end'].dt.to_period('Q')-df['start'].dt.to_period('Q')).apply(lambda x: x.n)
```